# Best Bitonic Sort algorithm

Tags: sorting

I was looking into the bitonic sort algorithm,

I realized there seems to be two forms of this algorithm:

Wikipedia Algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter

Alternate Algorithm
http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~venugopa/parallel_summer2012/bitonic_overview.html
(also the one used in the CUDA samples gallery)

Wikipedia Algorithm:

```
1 2 3 4

d c b a // start

c d a b // compare (1, 2) (3, 4)

b a d c // compare (1, 4) (2, 3)

a b c d // compare (1, 2) (3, 4)
```

Alternate algorithm:

```
1 2 3 4

d c b a // start

c d a b // compare (1, 2) (3, 4)

a b c d // compare (1, 3) (2, 4)
```

In this trivial example, the alternate algorithm seems to be more efficient

Are these two algorithms equivalent?

Is there any advantage to the first one?